# Can I add javascript within jQuery ready function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on my first ever web page!

I have used a lot of jQuery, now I am going to implement pure javascript but I am not sure where to add this? can I place it within the ready function of my jQuery or shall I add it in a different way.

Please, can you provide the example so that I can fully understand? As mentioned, it is the first ever website I am putting together.

Many thanks!

Comment: You can place within the ready function of your jequery

Comment: — Could you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: look at getScript

Comment: You have used jQuery a lot, yet you're now making your very first website? What am I missing here?

Comment: lmgtfy: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: *Can I add javascript within jquer ready function?* **Yes**. *in a different way*, create a JS file along with `document.ready` and call necessary functions accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did not understand is that Jquery is only a library for JavaScript. It's just a set of functions available to you for easier, faster writing of JavaScript. Either you use only the Jquery functions or native js, it doesn't change the end result.

When you do `$("#myID")` it's the same as you would do `document.getElementById("myid")`.

People use Jquery to go faster, that's all. you can mix jquery and javascript how you like it as long as you don't do stuff like `document.getElementById($("#myId"))` which is completly false.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they're both JavaScript, you can use whichever functions are appropriate for the situation.

In this case you can just put the code in a document.ready handler, like this:

```
$(function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";
    ctx.fillRect (10, 10, 55, 50);

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)";
    ctx.fillRect (30, 30, 55, 50);
  }
});
```